# Exporting items from “To Do” by Microsoft to Apple “Reminders”

Tags: reminders

I’ve been using “To Do” by Microsoft for several years now, but I’m considering the possibility to hand over to the Apple-native “Reminders” app. Is there a way to export all items (including lists, completed tasks, and so on) from “To Do” to “Reminders” automatically?

Comment: Does Microsoft To Do have an export function?

Comment: If you use To Do with an online service from Microsoft, then you can sign in with that account in iOS settings; Reminders will then show your reminders from the microsoft online service. If you want to move your reminders from the microsoft online service to e.g. iCloud you can move all of them in the Reminders app by selecting each reminder and move them to iCloud.